# Running python script in powershell

Tags: python, powershell, windows-10

I am trying to run a Pygame in windows 10 Powershell, I have tried using the  `python programName.py` command but it just returns an error telling me that no such file or directory exists, specifically, it says `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe: can't open file 'spaceshooter.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` . I don't have admin rights on this computer and I cannot use CMD either.

Comment: I don't think that you need admin rights to use python on cmd

Comment: Do you have both files, `programName.py` and `spaceshooter.py` in the same directory? And is that directory your current working directory in PowerShell?

Comment: @BlackThunder the cmd is completly locked down, it just says command prompt disabled by administrator. Press any key to continue

Comment: This seems like "child account" issues. You should head to http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that your computer is not able to find the find
the solution is to show the computer where it is located(the directory)

go to that folder where u have saved your program and copy the directory
then open powershell
then type `cd (paste the copied directory)`
then type `py programName.py` or `python programName.py`
now it should work ✌

Comment: soo i should say "cd documents" and then